# Should constructor parameters be declared final

Tags: java, constructor, final

I have seen codes where function parameters have been declared final. Surprisingly not seen code with constructor parameters declared final.

Eg:

```
public class Foo {

   public Foo(final int day, final int month, final int year) {
    ...
   }
}
```

Why is this not common ? Is there a concrete reason or just that fact that code becomes verbose ?

Comment: Well, what would it add other than extra characters?

Comment: it enforces good coding practices

Comment: Which question is this duplicate?

Comment: Read this https://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/code_advice_12_use_final

Comment: There's no concrete reason; shops that use the `final` parameter pattern should use it in ctors as well for consistency. I haven't found the usage inconsistencies you have. In any case, there's no technical reason ctor parameters shouldn't be consistent with method parameters.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The outcome isn't the same, because `final` enforces something generally considered a good practice (parameter reassignment). It eliminates one brand of coding error when setting instance properties if your naming convention allows it in the first place, and one brand of Java brain-fart (thinking reassignment will change the caller). Whether or not it's *worth* the verbosity is a separate issue (e.g., I don't use the pattern myself).

Comment: @DaveNewton: I wasn't aware of that (and removed my comment the moment I read it in Azzu's answer). That does change the situation, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are times when you **have to** declare them `final`:

```
public class Test {
  final Runnable runner;

  public Test(final String text) {
    runner = new Runnable () {
      @Override
      public void run () {
        System.out.println("Run: "+text);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

but generally you don't have to and IMHO it is just an unnecessary distraction.

Comment: For another viewpoint, see @Azzu's answer and the blog referenced by Tala above -- https://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/code_advice_12_use_final .

Answer (score 16):

Java always only passes a copy of the argument to the function. This means that the only thing that final on a parameter does is disallow assignment of the variable inside of the function.

Assigning to function parameters (no matter if it is in a constructor or any other function) is considered bad style, because this changes the meaning of the parameter from a function parameter to a function local variable. The meaning of the name is thus lost.

The second reason is that it could be possible for a class to have the field `field1` and the constructor to have a parameter named `field1`. Declaring the parameter final avoids errors like `field1 = field1;` when one actually meant `this.field1 = field1;`.

In essence, declaring final on a function parameter is a matter of taste and adds a little bit of safety (but good IDEs should warn about the assignment with no effect anyway). You will have to type more for that (arguably very small amount of) safety though, which is why it is not often used.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define them final however if you use them parameters in inner class it is forbidden pass parameters without final.

Check here :

http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/08/local-inner-classes/